# Heroku: accessing dyon's underlying operating system, to view ephemeral files

Tags: heroku

When using Heroku, is it possible for me to access the dyno's underlying operating system (for example using Putty)? In particular I'd like to view the ephemeral files for debugging.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly to the dyno to look at the files via

```
heroku run bash
```

which will drop you into a bash prompt for your dyno